# Where can I find the use-package dependecy in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

The package is not an internal command of Lisp, but you must install it, so I install things such as *straight.el*, but where can I find the following?

```
Error (use-package): Failed to parse package multiple-cursors: use-package: Unrecognized keyword: :general
Error (use-package): Cannot load centaur-tabs
Error (use-package): Failed to parse package company: use-package: Unrecognized keyword: :ghook
Error (use-package): Failed to parse package company-box: use-package: Unrecognized keyword: :ghook
Error (use-package): Failed to parse package yasnippet: use-package: Unrecognized keyword: :ghook
Error (use-package): Failed to parse package magit: use-package: Unrecognized keyword: :general
Error (use-package): Failed to parse package git-commit: use-package: Unrecognized keyword: :ghook
```

Yes, I tried to search for packages *ghook* and *general*, but I was unable to find these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a general solution: `:ghook` and `:general` are part of this package:

https://github.com/noctuid/general.el